# How to add DHL shipping tracking for customers?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipping, dhl, shipment-tracking

I know in "shipping methods" there is a module for DHL but the [knowledge-base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/shipping-carriers-dhl) says "DHL is available for international shipments, but is not used for local shipments". Also it tells me nothing about what the module does. Because of this I think this module is useless for me.

I want the user to view DHL shipping tracking. How can I do this?

**Update**

You can add a tracking number to an order. Looks like the DHL module will do what I need. Where do I get the account for this DHL API xmlpi-ea.dhl.com?

I installed the official [DHL Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dhl-intraship-7494.html) module but it's config page returns a 404 error. Also there is a [developer page](https://entwickler.dhl.de) where you can get an account.

Comment: if the config page inside of Magento returns a 404 - please log out and login from the admin interface. That is a common effect when installing new modules.

Comment: Please post your final answer. :-)

Comment: I still don't have a solution. DHL Plugin is running and with some tricks I can track the package from the admin page but the user does not get any tracking link.

Comment: Does the customer get mails when you create the shipment? The mail template for shipments should include the tracking code in case it is properly added to the backend.

Comment: Yes, if I click a checkbox it does send a mail including the tracking code. I guess I can modify the email template somehow so it converts this code into a tracking link to DHL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a simple solution is to edit the email template and add a tracking link:

```
http://nolp.dhl.de/nextt-online-public/set_identcodes.do?lang=de&zip=[ZIP]&idc=[TRACKINGNUMBER]
```